# Date stored as varchar in db, not able to manipulate data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am facing an issue as I was pulling data from API in which date format looks like "Fri, 01 Apr 2022 00:00:00 GMT" and is saved like that in db.

```
DateColumn
Fri, 01 Apr 2022 00:00:00 GMT
Fri, 01 Dec 2023 00:06:41 GMT
Fri, 01 Jan 2021 01:59:32 GMT
Sat, 02 Jan 2021 01:59:32 GMT
Wed, 31 May 2028 14:44:36 GMT
```

I am not sure if is possible in current state, but I need to make a query and order by DateColumn asc

DateColumn

```
Fri, 01 Jan 2021 01:59:32 GMT
Sat, 02 Jan 2021 01:59:32 GMT
Fri, 01 Apr 2022 00:00:00 GMT
Fri, 01 Dec 2023 00:06:41 GMT
Wed, 31 May 2028 14:44:36 GMT
```

Do I need to make a new column only with dates, or this can be achieved somehow

QUERY works as expected only where statement is not in charge

```
SELECT id, registrar, str_to_date(datecolumn, '%a, %d %b %Y %T') as expired, status FROM `domains` where datecolumn is not null and datecolumn != ' ' ORDER BY `expired` ASC
```

[image: print]

Comment: If you're storing your data as strings then it will be sorted as strings.  Store your data in a `DATETIME` column.  Your code will need to convert it first, but once you have an actual `DATETIME` value you can sort, manipulate, perform calculations, etc.

Comment: See [`str_to_date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible;

```
SELECT str_to_date('Fri, 01 Apr 2022 00:00:00 GMT', '%a, %d %b %Y %T');
```

returns `2022-04-01 00:00:00`. You can then order by your datetime value, like so;

```
SELECT t.datecolumn
FROM table t
ORDER BY str_to_date(t.datecolumn, '%a, %d %b %Y %T') ASC;
```

---

See [STR_TO_DATE(str,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for more information. Note that the TZ (GMT) is ignored by the `str_to_date()` function.

Comment: Welcome to  Stack Overflow. Excellent answer. Please keep participating.

Comment: @Job Curtis thank you.  When I add condition to WHERE statement it doesnt work, it prints null and empty. Please check query as update in question

Comment: @Marko I haven't been able to reproduce this issue. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6t7aLDmaFWHYHXat7oURmi/1 Can you demonstrate it?

Comment: I have tried, it still prints NULL values on top, please check image in question. Can I somehow print them on bottom

Comment: @Marko if you demonstrate on a fork of the fiddle I linked then someone might be able to tell you why you're getting that result.

Comment: I added to fiddle

Comment: You need to link the new fiddle - it doesn't overwrite the existing one.